# Silverlight File download from client

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, download

I have a Silverlight application that implements some basic CRUD operations on a fairly flat data set.  The application loads all the data onto the client to allow for quick editing (this is a fairly small data set no more that a couple K).  I would like to allow them to download the file as a CSV so they can edit the data locally.

I know i can set up a `HyperLink` button to a URL on my webserver and then server the data dynamically using a custom server handler.  But this seems kind of roundabout to me because the all the data is already all on the Client's machine (because the Silverlight application loaded it).

So i was wondering if there was a way to prompt the user for a file download and then dynamically generate the file download stream from Silverlight?

Comment: You mean you want to save a file from your Silverlight application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog(VS.95).aspx). It allows you to prompt the user to pick a spot to save the file, and then you have access to the file through the [SaveFileDialog.OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog.openfile(v=VS.95).aspx) method.